# Apply filter to business object

Tags: c#

Can someone help me how to filter data from business object?

Here is my sample code:

```
var allemps = empService.GetAllEmployees();
IEnumerable<Emp> emps;
if (allemps.IsFreeOfErrors)
{
       emps = allemps.Value.Contains("abc");
}
```

here `allemps.Value` is returning all employee data. But I want to filter `emps` whose name starts with "abc". How do I do this?

Comment: Have you tried/googled something before asking?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here is [linq to object examples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b)

```
var allemps = empService.GetAllEmployees();
IEnumerable<Emp> emps;
if (allemps.IsFreeOfErrors)
{
   emps = allemp.Where(w=>w.Value.StartWith("abc"));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
emps = allemps.Where(e => e.Value.StartWith("abc"));
```